# Validate xsd against xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I have just finished studying xml and xsd. I made my first xml document and I just want to make sure that I'm validating it right using xsd.

**My xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<user xmlns="http://localhost" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost user.xsd">
<name>
    <first>jack</first>
    <last>hals</last>
</name>
<name>
    <first>harry</first>
    <last>potter</last>
</name>
</user>
```

**My xsd code:**

```
<?xml vesion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://WWW.W3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost" xmlns="http://localhost" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="user" block="substitution" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" block="substitution">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string" default="jack" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" block="substitution" />
                    <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string" default="hals" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" block="substitution" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have tried an online validator and it said: `A pseudo attribute name is expected.`

What to do now?

Comment: "I have just finished studying xml and xsd". Oh dear. It looks to me as if you've just started...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?xml vesion="1.0"
```

should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"
```

(you'd missed an "r").  Also, namespace URIs are case-sensitive, so

```
xmlns:xs="http://WWW.W3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

needs to change to

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```